# This JQuery website wont work on IE11 f or some reason(Fade in's etc)

Tags: javascript, input, internet-explorer-11

I know this code should be working as i've done other websites where it works on both.

http://johslan.tk/

refuses to work in IE 11( The buttons dont do anything)

Comment: `http://projoh.altervista.org/jquery.slides.min.js` not found.

Comment: @papirtiger I tried using a diff library but still, nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you load the page in IE11 and then go to the Console in the F12 developer tools, you see the following Script error:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined
File: jquery-ui.min.js, Line: 1, Column: 3
```

Which indicates the page is loading JQuery-UI before it loads JQuery.

Looking at the source on http://projoh.altervista.org/ I see you have the following HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jqueryui", "1.5.2");
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try switching the two  tags and I am guessing it will fix the issue.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jqueryui", "1.5.2");
</script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried it but it's still not working(Buttons)